# Handling UART ISR during double buffer swap

Tags: c, buffer, interrupt, stm32, uart

I am working on a double buffer for the UART on a STM32F processor. The example below adds the data to a buffer every time the UART ISR runs. This buffer is then swapped when the main process wants to pull data off of it.

I am concerned about a possible corner condition. It is possible for the ISR to fire after I have swapped the buffers but before I have reset the receive buffer count. This would mean that my buffer size and count would be out of sync.

What is the best way to handle this corner case?

```
uint8_t rxBufferA[MAX_RX_BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t rxBufferB[MAX_RX_BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t *receivingBuffer;
uint8_t *processingBuffer;
volatile uint32_t rxBufferSize;

uart_isr() {
  receivingBuffer[rxBufferSize++] = RECEIVE_DATA_REGISTER
}


main() {

  receivingBuffer = &rxBufferA;
  processingBuffer = &rxBufferB;

  while(1) {

    if (rxBufferSize > 0) {
      uint32_t i = 0;
      uint8_t *ptemp = receivingBuffer;
      uint8_t bufferSize = 0;

      /* zero out processing buffer */
      memset(processingBuffer, 0, MAX_RX_BUFFER_SIZE);

      /* swap receiving and processing buffers */
      receivingBuffer = processingBuffer
      processingBuffer = ptemp;

      /* WHAT IF THE ISR FIRES HERE??? */         

      /* save off buffer size and reset count */
      bufferSize = rxBufferSize;
      rxBufferSize = 0;

      /* process rx data */
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: `receivingBuffer` should be `volatile`: It is shared between an ISR and normal code.  When you change that, put your compiler warnings to the maximum, because I'm seeing that there will be more than one "discards volatile qualifier".

Comment: BTW, when you set your compiler warnings you should also see that `main` should be `int main(void)` and the ISR `void uart_isr(void)` (now it's an implicit `int`, and it is not returning, so you have some problems)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito The example I provided was not supposed to be a rough sketch

Comment: Your compiler warning should be high as default.  So your sketches should at least compile without warnings.  If you use GCC or Clang `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` will block your compilation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need critical  section.  disable the user interrupt when  swapping the buffer.

BTW zeroing is not needed

Comment: But then I run into the corner case of missing an ISR and the associated data

Comment: @user8908459 You will not miss it. It will be waiting until you enable it again.